# Manually enter the if statement without changing the code in VSCode Debugging

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am debugging a piece of Typescript code and I want the program to enter an if block:

```
  if (
    semverSatisfies(
      checkedContract.metadata.compiler.version,
      '=0.6.12 || =0.7.0'
    ) &&
    checkedContract.metadata.settings.optimizer?.enabled
  ) {
```

The statement normally returns false. I want to override the result of the statement and enter the if block, without writing `if (true)` and having to build the program again. i know I can change the `?.enabled` variable but don't know how to override the function's return value. Is this possible?

Comment: can you re-define the `semverSatisfies` function with `semverSatisfies = () => true;`  in the debug console

Comment: Sure but then I'd need to rebuild the project. I was wondering if there's something I can do on the fly, similar to changing the variable values when debugging.

Comment: **NO**, like I said use the DEBUG CONSOLE and just redefine the `semverSatisfies` variable with the line I showed, maybe need to safe the old value in a temp var first

Comment: Ah ok. I redefined it and I can see it's redefined because it shows `[[FunctionLocation]]: @ repl:1`, but when I step into it, it still steps into the `semver` library's function. Am I doing something wrong? I pasted that exact line before calling the function.

Comment: why do you `step into`, just `step` and you should go to the first statement of the `if` block